# スプレッドシートで、シート連携について

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

スプレッドシートの商品管理について、

基本の商品管理のカレンダーのシート1があって、

その発売日付(A列)、商品名(B列)、その商品の基本情報(C-G列ぐらい)

その商品に関して、行わなければいけないタスクのチェックシートを、タスクごとにシートを作成し、管理をしたいと思っております。

タスクごとのシート(シート2)は、
シート1(基本の情報) から、
発売日付(A列)、商品名(B列)のみ連携したいと思っており、現在A,B列のみクエリ関数で表示させ、C列以降にチェックや、備考を記載しておりますが、こちらには問題があり、基本シートの行を入れ替えた際、タスクシートのA,B列は入れ替わるが、C列以降は、そのままなので、事故の元で...

では、基本のシートに普通に列を増やし記載したらいいじゃないかとはなるのですが、
タスクが多いため、不便そうでして(列を間違えてチェックしてしまう可能性も、なきにしもあらず。)

ご教授頂ければ幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

シート2のC列以降を手打ちしているといった状態でしょうか？
タスクが何に依存しているかにも依りますが、シート3にでもキーとタスクの対応表を配置して、
シート2のC列以降でvlookupなどでシート3を参照するのは如何でしょう。